# Disabling iAD with inApp purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'd like to hide the iAD banner when the user buy the inApp purchase, is it sufficient to "removefromsuperview" the adbannerview or i need something more?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938832/how-to-remove-ads-when-user-buys-in-app-purchase) link. hope u will get your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `removeFromSuperview`, you would also have to have some code to place content there when you removed the ads, or you can have content there already and when you remove the ads, they become visible again.

I think you should do something like this in your viewDidLoad:

```
if(removeiAdsPurchased){
    [iAd removeFromSuperview];
    content.hidden = NO;
}
```